# MySQL How to include in where two clause?

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

```
SELECT 
  cms_module_ladu_batch.id AS batch_id, 
  name, t1, cms_module_ladu_batch.date_changed AS date_ch, 
  t13, t2, t3, t4, bkuup, date_modified, date_created, 
  kogused.aadress AS aadress, 
  kogused.kogus AS kogus, 
  SUM(kogused.kogus) AS total 
FROM 
  cms_module_ladu_batch 
  LEFT JOIN kogused 
    ON cms_module_ladu_batch.id = kogused.bid 
WHERE 
  t2!='Sildid' 
GROUP BY 
  batch_id
```

Thats the MySQL code - the problem is following. I need to exclude rows where total is 0 and date_ch older than one month (date_cd format is "2011-01-01 00:00:00").
is it possible?
http://jsfiddle.net/tiitremmel/2mvrr/1/ - jsfiddle sample - first table is like mysql result is default and the second table is how the result should look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT    cms_module_ladu_batch.id AS batch_id,
          cms_module_ladu_batch.date_changed AS date_ch,
          kogused.kogus AS kogus,
          SUM(kogused.kogus) AS total 
FROM      cms_module_ladu_batch 
LEFT JOIN kogused ON cms_module_ladu_batch.id = kogused.bid 
WHERE     t2 != 'Sildid' 
GROUP BY  batch_id
HAVING    (
       (
          cms_module_ladu_batch.date_changed < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
          AND SUM(kogused.kogus) > 0
       )
    OR
           cms_module_ladu_batch.date_changed > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
           );
```

This were the final code that worked for me. Great thanks to all, but greatest to [Bjoern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/240680/bjoern) - your idea of code helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Add the date condition into the `WHERE`-statement and the exclusion of your `SUM` as a 
`HAVING`-statement. It should then look like this:

```
SELECT    cms_module_ladu_batch.id AS batch_id,
          cms_module_ladu_batch.date_changed AS date_ch,
          kogused.kogus AS kogus,
          SUM(kogused.kogus) AS total 
FROM      cms_module_ladu_batch 
LEFT JOIN kogused ON cms_module_ladu_batch.id = kogused.bid 
WHERE     t2 != 'Sildid' 
          AND (
                  (
                   cms_module_ladu_batch.date_changed < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
                   AND SUM(kogused.kogus) > 0
                  )
              OR
                  cms_module_ladu_batch.date_changed > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
              )
GROUP BY  batch_id;
```

Alternatively... use a UNION-Statement to glue two SELECTS together.

```
SELECT   cms_module_ladu_batch.id AS batch_id,
         cms_module_ladu_batch.date_changed AS date_ch,
         kogused.kogus AS kogus,
         SUM(kogused.kogus) AS total 
FROM     cms_module_ladu_batch 
LEFT JOIN kogused ON cms_module_ladu_batch.id = kogused.bid 
WHERE t2 != 'Sildid' 
         AND cms_module_ladu_batch.date_changed < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
GROUP BY batch_id 
HAVING total > 0
UNION
SELECT   cms_module_ladu_batch.id AS batch_id,
         cms_module_ladu_batch.date_changed AS date_ch,
         kogused.kogus AS kogus,
         SUM(kogused.kogus) AS total 
FROM     cms_module_ladu_batch 
LEFT JOIN kogused ON cms_module_ladu_batch.id = kogused.bid 
WHERE t2 != 'Sildid' 
         AND cms_module_ladu_batch.date_changed > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
GROUP BY batch_id;
```

Try both, see what fits best for your solution.

Comment: but still both clauses are doing their work but the result is not what i need. date part excludes all other dates, but i need to exclude only dates that row total is 0. thanks anyway :)

Comment: ok, I didn't get that from the first post. Just put the addition in the WHERE-statement into the HAVING-Statement and you should be fine with this.

Comment: could you be more specific? do you mean `HAVING total > 0 AND cms_module_ladu_batch.date_changed < '2011-01-01 00:00:00'`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Can you clarify what to exclude and what not to?

Comment: i added to the main question jsfiddle link with sample how it looks now and how could be the result. hope this clarifies.

Comment: Ah, ok! Let me put it into SQL-langage: You want 1) all results before last month with have total > 0 AND 2) all results since last month regardless of their total? I've adjusted my answer alot for this, take a look!

Comment: the first one gives error "Invalid use of group function" and second one "The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns"

Comment: Sorry, I can't refine it without the original tables. But you have two different conditions, so you have to separate them in order to archieve your goal.

Comment: i think i fond the solution and the problem of first code, but the idea of first code is exactly what i need. i'm going to do some test and if i found the right solution i'm gonna write it to here. Great thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  cms_module_ladu_batch.id AS batch_id, 
  name, t1, cms_module_ladu_batch.date_changed AS date_ch, 
  t13, t2, t3, t4, bkuup, date_modified, date_created, 
  kogused.aadress AS aadress, 
  kogused.kogus AS kogus, 
  SUM(kogused.kogus) AS total 
FROM 
  cms_module_ladu_batch 
  LEFT JOIN kogused 
    ON cms_module_ladu_batch.id = kogused.bid 
WHERE 
  t2!='Sildid' AND
  date_ch < date_sub(now(), interval 1 month)
GROUP BY 
  batch_id
HAVING 
  SUM(kogused.kogus) <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

To filter outside the GROUP BY clause you can use the HAVING keyword.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Answer (score 0):

Just add at the bottom:

```
HAVING (total<>0) AND (date_cd>=ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH))
```

Other reply (see comments):

```
HAVING (total<>0) OR (date_cd>=ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH))
```

Comment: this seems to be closest but still it removes all zeros - thats the problem. i need to remove zeros older than one month.

Comment: you wrote "I need to exclude rows where total is 0 and date_ch older than one month". It can be both "I need to exclude rows where (total is 0) and (date_ch older than one month)" or "I need to exclude rows where (total is 0 and date_ch older than one month)".